# Canada Federal Skill Worker work experience

Tags: canada

I have applied for PR under Canada Skill Worker 2014 and received positive eligibility review. CIC have sent my application from Sydney in Canada to my local visa office. In my application for my work experience I have included a letter from my current employer which shows I have 23 months experience. However it's been three months from the time I sent my application which basically makes my experience more than two years.

May the officer in visa office consider it as two year job experience if I send a new reference letter or do they count up to the date of my application? (My application is still under process) I am asking this because I have 3 years of experience in total which they may reject the first year as I don't have enough supporting document for that, so only 23 months left, while I need 2 years.

Comment: Sending more documents can delay the processing. I think they'll assume you're still employed, in any case they can always check with the employer themselves. It's their job to do such checks